# How to render list items in a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a small problem where I can't seem to reliably render list items inside of a form using MVC4.  Here is a small slug of code where the problem comes up:

```
  ...
  @{int count = Model.Details.Count;}
  @for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
    <tr class="added-item">
      <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Details[i].WidthFeet)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Details[i].WidthInches)
      </td>
  ...
```

Basically I am going through the loop, and adding rows as I go.  I have stepped through this process manually, and I have confirmed that the correct indexes / data are being used, and I have confirmed that the HTML is correct as far as names are concerned (properly indexed, etc.)  Despite these facts, the problem that I am having is that the values in all of the input boxes wind up being the same on a row by row basis.  Basically, if I change a field in one, that value will be displayed in all of the other rows when the form renders again.

Can anyone tell me what is going on, or how I can fix this ?

Comment: Try to replace the EditorFor to TextBoxFor

Comment: Not sure if this is related to the issue, but `x => Model.Details[i]` looks a bit strange. Wouldn't `x => x.Details[i]` be more natural?

Comment: @Andrei Definitely not related.  Both forms are equally natural / the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use foreach:

```
@foreach (var Item in Model.Details)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Item.WidthFeet)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => Item.WidthInches)
}
```

Comment: If you do that, then the indexing will be incorrect, and you won't be able to submit data.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Could you please try the below? It is working for me.. If it still load the same data, please have a look in to your model data whether it is pulling duplicate data.

```
**@for (int count = 0; count < Model.Details.Count; count++)
            {
            <tr class="added-item">
                <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Details[count].WidthFeet)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Details[count].WidthInches)
                </td>
            </tr>
            }**
```